# Unable to connect to IB TWS using IbPy python api

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ibpy, tws

I am trying to pull historical market data for various tickers using the code I found from [https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/](https://github.com/blampe/IbPy)

Within this repository, there is an example of how to request market data in file "fancy_marketdata.py". However, I am having trouble establishing a connection using following code :

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from time import sleep

# print all messages from TWS
def watcher(msg):
    print(msg)

# show Bid and Ask quotes
def my_BidAsk(msg):
    if msg.field == 1:
        print ('%s:%s: bid: %s' % (contractTuple[0],
                       contractTuple[6], msg.price))
    elif msg.field == 2:
        print ('%s:%s: ask: %s' % (contractTuple[0], contractTuple[6], msg.price))

def makeStkContract(contractTuple):
    newContract = Contract()
    newContract.m_symbol = contractTuple[0]
    newContract.m_secType = contractTuple[1]
    newContract.m_exchange = contractTuple[2]
    newContract.m_currency = contractTuple[3]
    newContract.m_expiry = contractTuple[4]
    newContract.m_strike = contractTuple[5]
    newContract.m_right = contractTuple[6]
    print ('Contract Values:%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s:' % contractTuple)
    return newContract


con = ibConnection(port=7496,clientId=100)
con.registerAll(watcher)
showBidAskOnly = True  # set False to see the raw messages
if showBidAskOnly:
    con.unregister(watcher, message.tickSize, message.tickPrice,
                   message.tickString, message.tickOptionComputation)
    con.register(my_BidAsk, message.tickPrice)
con.connect()
sleep(1)
tickId = 1


contractTuple = ('QQQQ', 'STK', 'SMART', 'USD', '', 0.0, '')
stkContract = makeStkContract(contractTuple)
con.reqMktData(tickId, stkContract, '', False)
sleep(10)
con.cancelMktData(tickId)
sleep(1)
con.disconnect()
sleep(1)
```

When I get to "con.connect()", it gives the following error message:

```
Server Version: 76
<error id=None, errorCode=None, errorMsg='Receiver' object has no attribute 'managedAccounts'>TWS Time at connection:20171225 13:38:01 EST

Exception in thread EReader:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XYZ/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/XYZ/anaconda3/ib/IbPy-master/ib/ext/EReader.py", line 113, in run
    self.m_parent.close()
  File "/Users/XYZ/anaconda3/ib/IbPy-master/ib/ext/EClientSocket.py", line 1714, in close
    self.wrapper().connectionClosed()
AttributeError: 'Receiver' object has no attribute 'connectionClosed'
```

Is it because I am using python 3.6? My TWS version 968.2h. Please any help would be greatly appreciated! The contract that I am trying to pull market data for is the two new futures contracts by CBOE and CME (GXBT and BRR, respectively) for bitcoin trading.

Comment: Your code looks ok.  What version of IBpy do you have, I just looked at the source at the github link you gave and managedAccounts is there (in ext/EWrapper.py).  You must be using an older version or something else is wrong.  Your code works for me.  Note that IB has it's own python API now and is probably a better choice.  http://interactivebrokers.github.io/#

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code, just confirm you are specifying the contract tuple.
Both of these exchanges recently set up the Bitcoin contracts you are requesting data for - - they may not have everything functioning smoothly yet - - the object is probably referring to something specific regarding your account type.

Based on my experience, I have found using the Anaconda Python distribution from

https://www.anaconda.com/download/

provides the most consistent installs. Provides everything the way you need it in one fell swoop...